# Dijkstra's algorithm to prevent any vertex on re on fire paths

Tags: algorithm, queue, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra

Let G = (V;E) be a directed graph with two weights we and re on each edge e. There
are two special vertices in this graph: c, the chemical plant, and a, the amphitheater. The
task is to create an evacuation plan from a to v for every vertex w in V in the event that
the chemical plant catches re. The time it takes the re to spread along an edge e is re.
The time to travel along an edge is we.

**I have to write an algorithm to find the shortest safe path from a to
v for each v in V : a path is safe if it does not include any vertex on re at the time that vertex is traversed.**

My trying:

i. I have first computed the time at which each vertex catches re , assuming the chemical plant catches re at time 0.

ii. Then I have modified Dijkstra's algorithm so that it does not use any vertex on re on the paths
it computes.

My Algorithm:

```
DijkstraShortestPath:
       1. graph[][] --> read the graph
       2. c <-- chemical plant
       3. a <-- amphitheater  
       4. for i --> 0 to V   
            queuePriority.add(i);
            distance[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            prev[i] = -1;
            visitedVertex[i] = false;
        }
        5. Q <-- queue(c), level[]--> inifinity
        6. while Q is not empty:
              U <-- Q.pop() 
   for all edges from u to v in G.adjacentEdges(c)
           If level[v] --> inifinity:
            level[v] <-- level[u] + re
            Q.enqueu(v)       
        7. distance[a] = 0;
        while (!queuePriority.isEmpty()) {

            int u = minDistance();
            if (u == -1) {
                break;
            }

            queuePriority.remove(u);
            visitedVertex[u] = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeNumber; i++) {
                if (graph[u][i] != 0 && graph[u][i]%re ==0 && graph[u][i] + distance[u] < distance[i]) {
                    distance[i] = graph[u][i] + distance[u];
                    prev[i] = u;
                }
            }
        }
        printShortestPath(distination);
        return distance[distination];
    }
```

Does my algorithm solve the problem ? If not, how can I modify my algorithm to solve the problem ?

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: Is my algorithm correct ?

Comment: If u need the shortest path between all pairf of vertices, then Bellman-Ford is the way to go